# Understanding Big O for power set

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have written an algorithm for power set written as P(a). Just learning about time complexities of algorithms (Big-O), so correct me if I am wrong.

Algorithm:

```
function powerSet(int[] a ){
ArrayList pw = new ArrayList();
pw.add(" ");
for (int i = 1; i <= a.length; i++) //O(n){
            ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (String e : pw)//O(n) {
                if(e.equals(" "))
                    tmp.add(""+a[i-1]) //contanst time;
                else
                    tmp.add(e+a[i-1]) //constant time;
            }
            pw.addAll(tmp)//O(1);
        }
        return pw;
}
```

Is the time complexity of this O(n)*O(n) = O(n^2), or it is an exponential function (c^n where c > 1) like 2^n, because I am enumerating all possible subsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of times the outer loop runs is `a.length`. The number of times the inner loop runs is `pw.length`, but this increases as the function runs. So you can't say that they're both `O(n)`. Also, `pw.addAll(tmp)` is not constant-time.

Here, the asymptotic time-complexity is the same as the number of times `tmp.add()` is called, which is equal to the final size of `pw`: `O(2^n)`.